# nginx: How to deploy an SPA and the backend api to a production server with different domains and port numbers

Tags: node.js, angularjs, nginx, single-page-application, web-deployment

I have to deploy an SPA to an nginx server. The backend API must be in the same server but with different domain and port.

Let's say the frontend domain is `front.example` and the backend domain is `back.example`.

- The frontend SPA should be running at `http://front.example:80`
- The backend API should be running at `http://back.example:4444`

What is the correct configuration in nginx server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/front.example**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name front.example www.front.example;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/back.example**

```
server {
    server_name back.example www.back.example;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:4444;
    }

}
```

**NOTE:** Be sure to include only `sites-enabled/*` in `etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.